# TMUX - entering vi mode key binding

Tags: configuration, tmux

I want to change entering vi mode key-set to **prefix + v** or **prefix + C-v**.

By default tmux uses **prefix + [** to enter vi mode. I tried to send-prefix + send-keys with bind but it didn't work.

I don't know if tmux allows such operations, but I think **prefix + [** is not very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting this in your .tmux.conf will do it:

```
bind 'v' copy-mode
```

You can find what keys are bound to what commands with:

```
tmux list-keys
```

Answer (score 10):

If you would like VI mode to be permanently enabled, add this line to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
```

Restart tmux or run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> then `source-file ~/.tmux.conf` inside of tmux.

[source](https://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/vi-mode-in-tmux/)